# Ошибка при создании объекта Request.Builder()

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

Подключил библиотеку Retrofit в build.gradle.

При создании объекта Request.Builder() в коде получаю ошибку:

'Request(okhttp3.Request.Builder)' is not public in 'okhttp3.Request'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

Как поправить?

Код:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), hello);

                Request request= new Request().Builder()
                        .url("http://91.122.56.48:8080/levelupchat/register")
                        .post(body)
                        .build();

                try {
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    Log.d(RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName(), response.body().string());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName(), Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что конструктор класса `Request` не имеет публичного конструктора. А вы пытаетесь создать его экземпляр.

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы статический класс `Builder`, являющийся внутренним для класса `Request` пытаетесь создать как не статический. Т.е., если ещё проще - удалите скобки:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
```

Comment: Это моя ***я невнимательность! И ведь не в первый раз уже! Благодарю! Все заработало.